# PHP access complex xml elements

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have the following XML file 
I would like to retrieve some value. 
TH problem that I tried to use x-path but it didn't work.

Here is the xml file:

```
<soap-env:Envelope>
    <soap-env:Header></soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <OTA_AirAvailRS Version="2.2.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete"></stl:ApplicationResults>
            <OriginDestinationOptions OriginTimeZone="Z2">
                <OriginDestinationOption RPH="1">
                    <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="01-05T01:05" DOT_Ind="N" DepartureDateTime="01-04T22:00" FlightNumber="642" RPH="1" SmokingAllowed="false" StopQuantity="0" eTicket="true">
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="1" ResBookDesigCode="J" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="0" RPH="2" ResBookDesigCode="Z" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="5" RPH="3" ResBookDesigCode="C" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="4" RPH="4" ResBookDesigCode="D" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="0" RPH="5" ResBookDesigCode="I" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="6" ResBookDesigCode="Y" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="7" ResBookDesigCode="B" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="0" RPH="8" ResBookDesigCode="P" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="9" ResBookDesigCode="H" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="0" RPH="10" ResBookDesigCode="W" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="11" ResBookDesigCode="K" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="0" RPH="12" ResBookDesigCode="R" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="13" ResBookDesigCode="M" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="14" ResBookDesigCode="L" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="15" ResBookDesigCode="V" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="16" ResBookDesigCode="S" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="17" ResBookDesigCode="N" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="18" ResBookDesigCode="Q" />
                        <BookingClassAvail Availability="9" RPH="19" ResBookDesigCode="O" />
                        <DaysOfOperation>
                            <OperationSchedule>
                                <OperationTimes>
                                    <OperationTime Fri="true" Mon="false" Sat="true" Sun="true" Thur="false" Tue="false" Weds="true" />
                                </OperationTimes>
                            </OperationSchedule>
                        </DaysOfOperation>
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KWI" />
                        <Equipment AirEquipType="E95" />
                        <FlightDetails Canceled="false" Charter="false" />
                        <MarketingAirline Code="RJ" FlightNumber="642" ParticipationLevel="DCA" />
                        <Meal MealCode="D" />
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="AMM" />
                    </FlightSegment>
                    <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="01-05T06:10" ConnectionInd="Y" DOT_Ind="N" DepartureDateTime="01-05T03:25" FlightNumber="859" RPH="2" SmokingAllowed="false" StopQuantity="0" eTicket="true"></FlightSegment>
                    <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="01-05T12:30" ConnectionInd="Y" DOT_Ind="N" DepartureDateTime="01-05T10:20" FlightNumber="501" RPH="3" SmokingAllowed="false" StopQuantity="0" eTicket="true"></FlightSegment>
                </OriginDestinationOption>
                <OriginDestinationOption RPH="2"></OriginDestinationOption>
                <OriginDestinationOption RPH="3"></OriginDestinationOption>
                <OriginDestinationOption RPH="4"></OriginDestinationOption>
            </OriginDestinationOptions>
        </OTA_AirAvailRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

I would like to retrieve the values from 'Flight Segment' element

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath should work:

```
    $soap = new DOMDocument();
    $soap -> preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;        
    $soap ->load([source url);

    $query = "//FlightSegment";
    $xPathObject = new DOMXPath($soap);
    $searchQuery = $xPathObject->query($query);
```

`$query = "//FlightSegment"`:  `//` selects nodes from where ever they are in the document. `FlightSegment` is a `node` and should be retrieved from the document with `xpath`.

There will be three `FlightSegment` nodes stored in the variable `$searchQuery`. You can access them with `$searchQuery->item(#)`, where `#` is the item index. In this case 0, 1 or 2.